# Use Flux in a DTO response

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

What is the best way to return from controller object with two flux(arrays) inside?

I have two reactive repositories. One with football clubs, another one with countries. I want to return dto like:

```
public record InitData(Flux<FootballClub> footballclubs, Flux<Country> countries){}
```

So I can return list instead of flux via .block but this is not good idea. How can I subscribe two repositories in controller and return two arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't return multiple `Flux` instances inside a DTO. Flux need to be subscribed somewhere in order to be useful. Assuming you have the following response DTO:

```java
public class Response  {

  private List<String> footballClubs;
  private List<Integer> countries;

}
```

You can use [`.collectList()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#collectList--) method to collect all entities emitted by your repository into a `List`:

```java
private Mono<List<String>> getFootballclubs() {
  return footballclubsRepository.select().collectList();
}

private Mono<List<Integer>> getCountries() {
  return countriesRepository.select().collectList()
}
```

And finally, map the resulting `Mono`s into the response DTO:

```java
Mono.zip(getFootballclubs(), getCountries())
      .map(tuple2 -> Response.builder().footballClubs(tuple2.getT1()).countries(tuple2.getT2()).build())
```

Note that this is a valid solution in case we have a limited number of clubs and countries.

Comment: Thank you. But I see one issue - getFootballclubs and getCountries don't work in parallel. I mean before I get countries, I have to get all football clubs, but this data is independent and I can get all of them in the same time. Do you know a soultion?

Comment: @FoxNet You can simply use `Mono#zip`. Edit made.

Comment: yes, I know about zip but as you said it has limitations. For me power of async is when I able to send multiple requests to different data sources and wait them all in the same time. But with wubflux I can't find a solution to do it. Of course I can create multiple threads, but this is not about asynchronous programming

Comment: @FoxNet zip gives you concurrent execution. The limitation came from the fact that `.collectList()` will buffer the content of the list in memory.

Comment: yeah. It works. Sorry, I did mistake with Flux zip. Flux creates pairs and I didn't receive all data, but  a list with the number of objects of the smallest list. So I thought Mono do the same.